# Cant run bash script example from "The linux command line, a complete introduction, 2nd"

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, zsh

Here is an example of my zsh script, that script was modified from original one:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# read-default.sh: supply a default value if user preses Enter key.

read -e -p "What is your user name? " -i $USER
echo "You answered: '$REPLY'"
```

Here is an original script from the book:

```
#!/bin/bash
# read-default: supply a default value if user presses Enter key.
read -e -p "What is your user name? " -i $USER
echo "You answered: '$REPLY'"
```

Here is a mistake what I've got after running zsh script:

```
read-default.sh: line 7: read: -i: invalid option
read: usage: read [-ers] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-p prompt] [-a array]
[-n nchars] [-d delim] [name ...]
```

I will be appreciate for any help! :)

Comment: You cannot use the `-i` option for `read`

Comment: Oh, thanks, but how I can run this script another way?

Comment: you need to check if `$REPLY` is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was thinking about it!

Comment: Using zsh with a bash book, or the inverse, isn't a great practice; they're different shells, with different extensions and different deviations from POSIX sh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you see in your shell's error message, you cannot use the `-i` flag when calling `read`. To solve your problem you need to check if `$REPLY` is empty and supply a default value if it is.

Comment: Cant vote up your answer, dont have reputation, thanks again. :)

Comment: @kostyawhite, owww, what a pity :-)

Comment: Yeah, cause that's my first question here, and you are the first person who helped me!

Comment: You mean your answer?

Comment: @kostyawhite, yeah, what else? :)

Comment: @kostyawhite, thanks. BTW, it's good practice on SO to accept answers that helped you. Other people can up- or downvote them.

Comment: Can you advise a good book about shell scripting? I'm just started to learn it.

Comment: @kostyawhite, well, to my mind there are lots of them, try googling! As for me, one of the best ways of learning BASH is just to google "bash tutorial" and see the top-10 sites. It might be better than any book.

Comment: @kostyawhite If you're using the latest release of GNU BASH then have a look at: [The GNU Bash Reference Manual, for Bash, Version 4.3.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf)

Comment: @ForceBru, many of the online references for bash are actively counterproductive, making "just use Google" questionable advice. The ABS, for instance, is somewhat notorious for using bad practices in code used to demonstrate features; folks who are already experts know when it's doing something just for purpose of an example that shouldn't be copied, but for something written for beginners that's dangerous behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What language is your script written in?

Shell scripts written in `bash`, `zsh`, and `sh` differ slightly.

It seems your are using `bash` features, but run the code with `sh`.

The `read` command is a shell builtin. Have a look at the corresponding man pages to find out what kind of options are allowed for your shell.

For your example it should be enough to change the shebang (first line) back to `#!/bin/bash` or run the script explicitly with `bash read-default.sh`.

Comment: I'm using zsh as my login shell, I solved this issue already, changed shebang as you said, and run script with `bash`, thanks!